# Dealing with rxjs observables logic

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    this.data.getPersonalData(myfilter),
    this.peopleService.selectedPerson,
).subscribe(([data, person]) => {
    this._data = data;
    if (this._data.length) {
        this.infoService.getInfo(
            person.id
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.handleInfo(res);
        });
    }
});

Observable.combineLatest(
    this.data.getPersonalData(myfilter),
    this.sectionService.selectedSection
).subscribe(([data, section]) => {
    this.filterbySection(s);
});
```

I will try to explain the scenario:

First we get all personaldata available given by `myfilter`. Okey, so now, given a `selectedPerson` we get all the info for a person, and `handleInfo` associates this info for a group of objects in `data`. But the thing is, when it finishes I want to `filterbySection` when I have a `selectedSection`.

I know I can put `this.sectionService.selectedSection` in the first `combineLatest`, but every time the user changes the section, it will run the `infoService` going to the database and bringing all the info, I do not need this behaviour. I need to run `getInfo` when I select a person, handle this info mapping it to `_data`, and then filter by section all the whole thing "info + data", each time the user clicks on a new section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about this solution. But I could create an `EventEmitter` for `info`, so then I can subscribe to the `personalInfo`, and in the second `combineLastest` I would have something like:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    this.infoService.selectedInfo,
    this.sectionService.selectedSection
).subscribe(([info, section]) => {this.filterBySection(info, section)});
```